# Setup HTTPS on mediawiki on docker

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, mediawiki

I learn docker (Yes I am a noobie) and I want to setup HTTPS on my mediawiki container. I don't find any documentations or sample. When I try to set up by changing the 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
```

I use [OFFICIAL REPOSITORY for mediawiki](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/)

After this, my container don't start.
Thanks for the help.